# Write to csv and I get error : _csv.Error: sequence expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Please help. I get an error when I want to write my dict `AllListInstance` to csv file. This is my code:

```
AllListInstance= {frozenset(['OFFENSE INVOLVING CHILDREN']): [(95,), (96,), (35,), (80,), (100,)], frozenset(['BATTERY', 'THEFT']): [(173, 209), (173, 224)]}

with open('test1.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
   for key in AllListInstance.keys():
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(len(AllListInstance[key]))
    for y in range(len(key)):
        csv_writer.writerow([x[y] for x in key])
        csv_writer.writerow(x[y] for x in AllListInstance[key])
```

output expected:

```
5   # len(AllListInstance["OFFENSE INVOLVING CHILDREN"]) count of member
OFFENSE INVOLVING CHILDREN
95
96
35
80
100
2 # len(AllListInstance['BATTERY','THIEF']) count of member
BATTERY        THIEF
173            209
173            224
```

Error:

```
    csv_writer.writerow(len(AllListInstance[key]))
_csv.Error: sequence expected
```

Solusion for my expected ouput:

```
with open('test8.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
  for key in AllListInstance.keys():
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow([len(key),len(AllListInstance[key])])
    csv_writer.writerow(list(key))
    for x in AllListInstance[key]:
        csv_writer.writerow(list(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in a *single integer*:

```
len(AllListInstance[key])
```

That's not a sequence, which is what `csv_writer.writerow()` expects. If you want to write one column with the length value, wrap that in a list:

```
csv_writer.writerow([len(AllListInstance[key])])
```

Comment: next error comes : `csv_writer.writerow(x[y] for x in key)
_csv.Error: sequence expected`

Comment: @ErnaPiantari: again, add `[...]` brackets; a generator expression isn't supported, the result of a list comprehension is.

Comment: for `csv_writer.writerow([x[y] for x in key])` my expected output is print string `OFFENSE INVOLVING CHILDREN`, But using my code , the output is only the first character `O`. Can you give me suggestion?

Comment: Why not just use `csv_writer.writerow(key)` instead? No need to loop there. You can write the value for each key with `csv_writer.writerows(AllListInstance[key])`.

Comment: `AllListInstance.values()` is frozen set. When I print `csv_writer.writerow(key)` the output is `frozenset(['BATTERY', 'THEFT'])`.  I want to split become `BATTERY` and `THEAF` and print to different coloum.

Comment: @ErnaPiantari: `csv_writer.writerow(list(key))` then :-) But take into account that the order can vary between runs; a set has no set ordering.